# Git: How to download entire history of a single file?

Tags: git, gitlab

There's a particular file on my Git that's been updated numerous times. I would like to download this file from all the commits so that I can compare the evolution of the file across commits. Since there are so many commits I'm interested in, I don't want to manually download this file for each commit as that would take a very long time. Is there any way to automatically download this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't clone the repository and use something like `git log --patch -- path/to/file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a copy of each version of the file, I have a script `get-versions` that will do that.

https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/get-versions